Populating Cache in microservices
These days I was asked by our technological leader to populate a cache.
The exact nature of the request impacts a back-end (BE) system that operates on a database through a client library.
The BE is a Java Spring Boot application and the client library carries out its operations and internally maintains its Caffeine cache.
It can happen the system takes a few hundreds of milliseconds to answer client requests; partly due to the high complexity of carried-out checks and to a single instanced slow database, on which I can't operate.
The request about populating the cache has been justified as a strategy to avoid a set of requests to the BE system to prevent slowdowns the client library could suffer. The client library is in turn exploited by a third BE to provide service.
Here is a synthetic version of the schema: 3rd BE <=> library (cache here) <=> BE 1 <=> DB.
One important detail about BE 1 is that the DB is responsible for storing entities and generating keys, that are incremental integers. The strategy he suggested is to update the library and allow adding the entity to the cache, in such a way that when requests are made cache hits will prevent BE 1 from being queried. This, in turn, prevents the entity from being persisted on the database (it should be persisted later).
To me, this request is absurd.
It presents problems on several fronts:

concurrency issues,
cache clearing problems,
lack of persistency,
high programming costs,
high maintenance costs.

One strategy to achieve this result is to query the database and identify the ID the entity should get when persisted, add the entity to the cache, and then persist it to the database.
When an entity is actually persisted I should check whether the ID has been already taken by another concurrent write and check they do not conflict. In case the ID has been taken by another entity I should clear and re-populate the cache.
The question is, are there alternatives to this (anti-)pattern?

Why not immediately cache a new object after it has been created by the DB?

The question is unreadable.
Is the suggestion to populate the cache when a new entity is added, without actually writing it to DB? Basically, write-cache?

@Basilevs Exactly.

@Ccm My colleague wants to avoid the time spent waiting for the DB to persist the entity. The library currently behaves that way, persisted entities are stored in the cache.

When entity would be considered ready to be persisted?

@Basilevs At any moment after inserting it into the cache; he wants to prevent the 3rd BE from being stuck waiting for BE 1. In such a way the front-end can proceed with other operations.

@Chaos, there is a very big difference with polluting a cache (filling it with nonsense, so will nearly always have to hit BE 1) or populating a cache (pre-filling it with entries not yet requested, based on the assumption that those entries will be requested soon). Can you update your question to make it clear which one you mean?

@BartvanIngenSchenau Sure.

Your concerns 1,2,3 are solved by UUID or a sharded identifier (where part of identifier is either globally unique or identifies a library instance).
It would take some time to implement, but maintenance would not be a concern.
In general, write cache is a well-explored topic and should not be conceptually hard (just a tad harder than read cache).
One point to care about is about loss of atomic consistency of data across multiple instances of library. You have already solved that somehow with your read cache invalidation procedure, that invalidation may require an overhaul.

I will have a look into that solution, perhaps it is feasible for our organization.
